# How to match element atrribute values in XML using java?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have xml file with id as attribute.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <animalguesser>

<query id = "1" >


  <data> Welcome to Animal Guessing Game !!!!!!! </data>

    <choices>

        <choice jumptoid = "2" > continue </choice>
        <choice jumptoid = "39" > exit </choice>

    </choices>

 </query>

 <query id = "2" >
   <data> Is this a mammal ? </data>

    <choices>

        <choice jumptoid = "3" > yes </choice>
        <choice jumptoid = "11" > no </choice>

    </choices>
```

I have parsed xml file using DOM, what I wish to do is take input from user ,match it with choice jumptoid and return result and continue, is there way I can do this in dom and java? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String outputString="Your xml string";      
Document document = parseXmlFile(outputString);
javax.xml.xpath.XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
System.out.println("Enter number ");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = sc.nextInt();
sc.close();
Element e = (Element) xpath.evaluate("//query[@id='"+i+ "']", document, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

Tested with sample XML and it worked.

Refer to this site also for some syntax rules

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/

Comment: hi, thanks for replying, this does display output as continue or exit, what I wish to do is take input from user, for example if its continue press 1 and then I need to match with choice jumptoid which is 2 and it should then display data of query id 2.

Comment: Modified to get Input from user and get the text based on the provided ID. Use scanner and hashmap inside.. It may help